# Transpose/Pivot a table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I am trying for hours to transpose one table into another one this way:

[image: Visual Illustration of Dynamic Transpose]

My idea is to grab on an expression (which can be a simple SELECT * FROM X INNER JOIN Y ...), and transpose it into a MATERIALIZED VIEW.

The problem is that the original table can have an arbitrary number of rows (hence columns in the transposed table). So I was not able to find a working solution, not even with [colpivot](https://github.com/hnsl/colpivot).

Can this ever be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select "user", 
       max(value) filter (where property = 'Name') as name, 
       max(value) filter (where property = 'Age') as age,
       max(value) filter (where property = 'Address') as addres
from the_table
group by "user";
```

A fundamental restriction of SQL is, that all columns of a query must be known to the database *before* it starts running that query.

There is no way you can have a "dynamic" number of columns (evaluated at runtime) in SQL.

---

Another alternative is to aggregate everything into a JSON value:

```
select "user", 
       jsonb_object_agg(property, value) as properties
from the_table
group by "user";
```

Comment: Can this be done with a plugin for postgres?

Comment: No, because you can't overcome the fundamental restriction that the columns must be know _before_ the query is executed (when the SQL is parsed)